# CakePHP Exception change template

Tags: templates, exception, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

How to replace just one exception template for own exception inside a plugin, which is extended built-in exception? :)

Exception located is in `/vendor/author/pluginName/src/Exception/TestException.php`

But i try replace template by create file `/src/Template/PluginName/Error/test.ctp` but doesn't work.

Of course, if I create file inside `/src/Template/Error/test.ctp` works fine.
I have many plugins and each can has own `TestException` class.

So, How I can use `/PluginName` direcotry?

Cake 3.6

Comment: You mean `/vendor/author/pluginName/src/Template/Error/test.ctp`, don’t you?

Comment: I am not positive which is why I am commenting instead of answering but I believe you could create a custom exception renderer class that extends `ExceptionRenderer` and provides logic for whatever custom exceptions you want to handle. Inside each custom exception method you can explicitly render an error template. See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#customize-error-templates for more information.

Comment: @Mary This is default template from plugin, but I would like rewrite it for my style:)

Comment: No, please compare the path I posted with the second one in your question.

Comment: @Mary Your path is correct if plugin has template, but I would like rewrite

Answer (score 0):

The correct template path for overriding a plugin template on app level starts with `Template/Plugin/`, followed by the plugin name and the expected local template path, ie for a plugin named `Foobar`, the path for overriding its `test` error template would be:

```
src/Template/Plugin/Foobar/Error/test.ctp
```

Also it's important to keep in mind that error templates will by default only be looked up in plugins, if the exception is being triggered in a plugin controller request, to be specific, when the current global request object (`Router::getRequest(true)`) has a plugin parameter set (`$request->getParam('plugin')`)!

It should also be noted that individual templates that map to exception/method names, will only be used for non-HTTP exceptions (`\Cake\Http\Exception\HttpException`), and only when debug mode is enabled, if it's a HTTP-Exception or debug mode is disabled, then only the `error400` or `error500` template will be used!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Plugin Views > Overriding Plugin Templates from Inside Your Application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application)**

Comment: I rebuild to non-HTTP exception and set debug mode to enabled and works fine, thanks!. But there is option to working when debug mode is disabled?

Comment: @kicaj No, there is no such option, you'd have to create a custom/extended exception renderer in order for that to be possible, look into **[\Cake\Error\ExceptionRenderer::_template()](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.6.12/src/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php#L279)**, this where it happens.